How to use Bulloak in Github CI workflow?
I am using Bulloak to write integration tests for my smart contracts using Foundry. The integration tests use BTT technique. Bulloak helps me to automatically create test contract based on the tree structure. However, during new PRs it becomes difficult to review the tests by comparing it with BTT specs.
Is it possible to use Bulloak in the Github CI so that the CI can ensure that tests are written in the same structure as the tree specs?

Yes, you can use the Bulloak in the CI to automate BTT checks. An example below:
name: "Verify the specs of concrete tests using bulloak"

on: "workflow_call"

jobs:
  bulloak-check:
    runs-on: "ubuntu-latest"
    steps:
      - name: "Check out the repo"
        uses: "actions/checkout@v4"

      - name: "Install Rust"
        uses: "actions-rs/toolchain@v1"
        with:
          toolchain: "stable"

      - name: "Cache cargo"
        id: cache-cargo
        uses: "actions/cache@v4"
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.cargo/bin/
            ~/.cargo/registry/index/
            ~/.cargo/registry/cache/
            ~/.cargo/git/db/
            target/
          save-always: true
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-

      - name: "Install bulloak or use the cached version"
        if: steps.cache-cargo.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: "cargo install bulloak"

      - name: "Verify the concrete tests"
        run: "bulloak check test/integration/concrete/**/**.tree --skip-modifiers"

      - name: "Bulloak summary"
        run: |
          echo "## Bulloak result" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY
          echo "✅ Passed" >> $GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY

The above example also caches the Cargo package so that it does not compile Bulloak on every run. It only compiles when the Cargo.lock file changes.
